# Can photorespiration do any good?

Tags: cell-biology, plant-physiology, photosynthesis

When CO2-levels are to low plants start to photorespirate instead of photosynthesise. This cost them losses in energy, and adds CO2 to the atmosphere instead of O2.

I wonder if the photorespiration is entirely "bad" for the plant or is there any beneficial outcome as well?

Comment: Honestly, I do believe that photorespiration has hidden advantages for plants. Yet, the answers to this question will most likely be primarily opinion-based.